# Inquiry about the problem in the canvas function

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Why can't it function properly? The block doesn't move at all when the button is clicked. Originally, the website can function normally, but after changing the size of the block for a few times, the website suddenly can't function. Would anyone help me figure the problem out? Thank you so much!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style>
canvas{border:1px solid black;)
</style>
<script>
var canvas;
var ctx;
var rect_x=0;
var rect_y=0;
function animate()
{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  rect_y+=5;
  canvas = document.getElementById("Mycanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.fillRect(rect_x,rect_y,50,50); 
  if (rect_y>=canvas.height-50);
  {clearInterval(timer);}
}
function draw()
{
  rect_x = 0;
  rect_y = 0;
  canvas = document.getElementById("Mycanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  timer = setInterval("animate()",50);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="Mycanvas" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
<br/>
<button onclick="draw()"> Draw</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "the website suddenly can't function" is not very specific. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53637041/edit) to let us know what the expected result is and how your code fails to achieve it? [Reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may be useful. Also, please edit the title of your question to be more specific. Note that people may decide whether or not they actually look into your question after reading just the title.

Answer (score 1):

**Typo** you have a semicolon after your `if()` condition in

```
if (rect_y>=canvas.height-50);
```

This is equal to "do nothing if `rect_y >= canvas.height - 50`"

```
if (rect_y >= canvas.height - 50)
    ;
```

and means your next block `{clearInterval(timer);}` will always get called.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style>
canvas{border:1px solid black;)
</style>
<script>
var canvas;
var ctx;
var rect_x=0;
var rect_y=0;
function animate()
{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  rect_y += 5;
  canvas = document.getElementById("Mycanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(rect_x,rect_y,50,50); 
  if (rect_y>=canvas.height-50) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
function draw()
{
  rect_x = 0;
  rect_y = 0;
  canvas = document.getElementById("Mycanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  timer = setInterval("animate()",50);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="Mycanvas" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
<br/>
<button onclick="draw()"> Draw</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But note that there would be a lot to say about your code, starting by

- don't use setInterval for visual animations, always prefer [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.
- Also, never use evil eval even implicitely as in `setInterval("someFunc()", t)`, instead pass a reference to the callback directly as in `setInterval(someFunc, t)`.
- And never ever overwrite a setInterval timeout before you cleared it. With your current code, if you click several times before the condition is met, you'll have several setIntervals running until your page dies.

Comment: @SusanLee don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. By the way, aside the semicolon typo, you have another one: `canvas{border:1px solid black;)` – the closing bracket should be curly as well

Comment: But since it is a typo, and that it is very unlikely it will help anyone in the future you can also just delete your question. I already voted to close it, but this will avoid for other reviewers to come in. @SusanLee

Comment: @Kaiido you commented the answer and haven't mentioned the asking person

Answer (score 0):

You should always strive to make your code scalable and reusable, while keeping it as clear and simple as possible. Something like the below takes care of the errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<canvas id="Mycanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas> 
<script>
var c=document.getElementById("Mycanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var rect_x=0;
var rect_y=0;
var rectHeight = c.height/10;
var rectWidth = c.width/10;

function animate(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
drawNew();
if (rect_y+5<=c.height-rectHeight){
rect_y+=5;}
}

function drawNew(){
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(rect_x, rect_y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
}

setInterval(animate,50); 

</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: it's actually a model answer from my professor. He told me that the reason to set x,y values to 0 is just in case of anything wrong, the value has been declared, and which will not make anything 'undefined' occurs.

Comment: and if I declare canvas and ctx before the functions, the whole website cannot even function... I have tried that before.. and this method is also followed my professor's method.. >< Thank you anyway. I have tried to check the above code with the model answer (which can really function perfectly), and they are really exactly the same, so this really confused me what's wrong with the above code :( but I guess we cannot figure out the problems..

Comment: but it is perfectly fine when I use this code, which seems exactly the same as the above code:
var canvas;
var ctx;
var rect_x=0;
var rect_y=0;
function animate()
{ ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

rect_y+=5;
canvas= document.getElementById("Mycanvas");
 ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="red";
 ctx.fillRect(rect_x,rect_y,50,50); 

 if (rect_y>=canvas.height-50)
 {clearInterval(timer);}
 
}

Comment: Regardless of if it supposedly "works" or not, the coding is not proper. There are many elements that are not necessary, out of place, or just plain wrong.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your detailed reply! Then my professor may have taught us something not really proper, but sadly, we still need to follow his way in the examination.